# SQL Server xp_regread access denied

Tags: sql-server

I have a client that is having an 'Access Denied' to a call to xp_regread (trying to find the database path), but I cannot seem to reproduce this. I have tried running the following

```
REVOKE execute on xp_regread to public
```

But it still works. I also found some articles on SQL Server 2000 problems (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/887165) but the clients server is 2005. Any ideas on how to go about fixing this problem.

Edit: I have tried the following

```
USE MASTER
GO

REVOKE execute on xp_regread to public
GO

DECLARE @InstanceName nvarchar( 128 )
SET @InstanceName = ISNULL( CONVERT( nvarchar( 128 ), SERVERPROPERTY( 'InstanceName' ) ), N'MSSQLSERVER' )
DECLARE @InstanceKey nvarchar( 128 )
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL\', @InstanceName, @InstanceKey OUTPUT

print @InstanceName
print @InstanceKey
```

But it is still working. To be clear, I am trying to reproduce an issue where the call does NOT work. Revoking permissions was one way that I read should do it, but it still works for me.

Comment: What is the problem? You want a user to run it, or don't want? I ask because you have REVOKE

Comment: I want it to be able to run. A user is running into a problem where they get 'Access Denied' and I'm trying to figure out why/reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's an extended stored procedure so needs

```
EXEC master..xp_regread ...
```

Then, it would be

```
USE master
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON xp_regread TO public
GO
```

If an explicit DENY has been set then REVOKE will remove it. This is not the same as GRANT though. This only applies to a normal user.

Anyone with sysadmin rights or db_owner in master (sa is dbo in master) will bypass permissions anyway

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly `DENY` the permission:

```
GRANT DENY ON xp_regread TO XYuser.
```

Be careful though, it might cause issues later. Like the backup dialog in SSMS won't work for that person.

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce the issue, first you have to make a difference between two different errors: 'Access is denied.' and 'EXECUTE permission was denied'.

The first error is due to a configuration issue over a non sysadmin user. The second is due to lack of execute permission over the extended procedure.

For both please follow the post [How to configure permissions for xp_regread](https://sql.itrio.net/2013/09/04/how-to-configure-permissions-for-xp_regread-and-xp_instance_regread/)